# Logging into ADW Database Actions on my machine logs me out of my other session

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

I noticed that I can have just one user connected to Database Actions on an ADW instance. When I try to connect an additional concurrent user, the first user gets disconnected. How can I connect multiple users concurrently to Database Actions?

Answer (score 0):

When you open a session for Database Actions, browser cookies are used for maintaining authentication/authorization state, so if you want to have multiple windows for different database users connecting concurrently, you should connect on multiple browsers or use incognito/private browsing mode.